# Show that $\sup_{i\in I}d\left(x_{i},y_{i}\right)$ induces a topology stronger than the product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\left(X,d\right)$ be a bounded metric space.
Consider $\mathbb{X}=\prod_{i\in I}X$ for some $I$ an arbitrary set of indexes, with the metric $d_{\sup}$ defined $d_{\sup}\left(x,y\right)=\sup_{i\in I}d\left(x_{i},y_{i}\right)$. Then the topology $\tau_{\sup}$ induced by $d_{\sup}$ is "stronger" than the product topology $\tau_{prod}$.

I know that $\mathcal{C}=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left\{ \pi_{i}^{-1}\left(U_{i}\right):U_{i}\in\tau_{i}\right\} $ is a subbase for the product topolgy, I want to show that for every $B$ in the basis of the product topology and $x\in B$ there's an $x\in A \subseteq B$ in the basis for $\tau_{\sup}$. I can't figure out how to use the fact that the initial metric space is bounded.

Comment: If the metric would not be bounded and the index set $I$ is infinite then $d_{\text{sup}}$ is not well defined. Further it plays no essential role by proving the statement. This because for every metrizable topology we can find an appropriate bounded metric.

Answer (score 3):

"stronger" is used in a weak sense: the two topologies can coincide.(For example $X=\{0\}$, $I=\{1\}$).

The product topology can be characterized as the smallest topology which make each $\pi_i$ continuous. Clearly each $\pi_i$ is continuous w.r.t the metric $d_{sup}$. Hence, the product topology is contained in the topology of $d_{sup}$.